# Having trouble setting up spring+hibernate maven project?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-boot

I'm trying to setup a simple spring+hibernate project but keep getting the following stack traces...I've pasted my pom configuration below as well.

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.5.RELEASE)

2016-06-10 23:01:12.744  INFO 19668 --- [           main] com.package.tests.Test                : Starting Test on JamesWMAC.local with PID 19668 (/Users/james/apps/xx/target/classes started by james in /Users/james/apps/xx)
2016-06-10 23:01:12.747  INFO 19668 --- [           main] com.package.tests.Test                : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-06-10 23:01:12.762  INFO 19668 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@70a9f84e: startup date [Fri Jun 10 23:01:12 EST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-06-10 23:01:12.771 ERROR 19668 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed


java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/config/EmbeddedValueResolver
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.<init>(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:72) ~[spring-context-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:632) ~[spring-context-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:516) ~[spring-context-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at com.package.tests.Test.main(Test.java:33) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.EmbeddedValueResolver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

Here is my pom.xml file:

<

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.package.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>package</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <org.springframework-version>4.3.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    </properties>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>mysql</groupId> <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId> 
            <version>6.0.2</version> </dependency> -->

        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.39</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JAVA servlet dependcies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                </dependency>
    </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>com.package.tests.Test</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
</project>
```

And my servlet-context.xml, I'm not sure this is contributing to any of the errors though:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.package.spring" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

 Injects DAO into spring controller  
<bean id="userDAO" class="com.package.dao.userDAO">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/webapp/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

I've spent soooo long trying to get this to work....

Comment: Work with the framework... You want to use spring boot but are trying very hard not to use spring boot. Instead of individual dependencies use the `spring-boot-starter-*`s. Instead of xml use java config (basically you can remove everything you have as Spring Boot auto configures that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First your pom is a bit of a mess. Use the `spring-boot-starter` projects instead of individual jars.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

     <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
     <dependency>
         <groupId>mysql</groupId>
         <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
     </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Should be all you need. I you want a specific version of hibernate use a `hibernate.version` property.

```
<properties>
    <hibernate.version>5.2.0.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>
```

**Note:** Spring (Boot) doesn't yet work with hibernate 5.2!

Next remove your Spring xml configuration file.

Put the credentials for your database in `application.properties` and instead of plain hibernate use JPA instead.

Also in your pom remove the assembly plugin, as the Spring Boot Plugin already takes care of that and the assembly plugin generates a wrong jar file.

Comment: Yeah I'm relatively new to Java and how it's packaging works...Coming from a node-js + python background I thought it may be easy. Do you know of any good tutorials or starter kits that'll get me going with hibernate ORM + spring? I'm just trying to build a rest API!

Comment: Great I'll go through it tomorrow, would you recommend I use gradle or maven? From what I know, gradle is newer, but maven seems to support a lot more stuff?

Comment: @M.Deinum  The personal spring frameworks should be delete?